# Is there an app that blocks certain search words on kindle fire?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-4, amazon-kindle-fire

http://bucknacktssordidtawdryblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/dont-filter-me-from-aclu-15feb11.html?m=1I  want to block certain words like "pornographic" on search engines like Yahoo, Google, Bing, etc without blocking my whole search engines. Is there anything on the kindle fire HD that can do that or apps. Is there any apps that I can download to my silk browser as I do not want to install other browsers to block words and sites and videos. Any downloadable content at all? I have an obsession which my self-control of it is spiraling so if I can just find an app, software,  etc. Anything at all to block playlist,  videos, search words, anything related to thr obsession like this:
 It would gladly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See
 http://www.google.com/goodtoknow/familysafety/tools/

http://m.internet-safety.yoursphere.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Finternet-safety.yoursphere.com%2F2012%2F12%2Fhow-to-make-the-kindle-fire-safe-and-age-appropriate-for-your-child%2F#2941

Google search:   safe search kindle fire

---

If you really want to use an APP here are a couple of apps, separate search engines, and a search at the Play store to find others.  I don't think any provide for you selecting your words. Have attempted to eliminate those that are "Free Trial" and want money afterwards, but that is not always successful.  Check out ratings, descriptions and comments on each app.

- [**Safe Search - Android Apps on Google Play**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waconiasoftware.safesearch)
   
  Worried about what you or your kids might see on the web? Safe Search is an app that leverages Google's "safe search" feature that filters out inappropri...
- [**Parental Control and Dashboard - Android Apps on Google Play**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.educren.kidsworld)
   
  Best Android Parental Control Apps Lock and Launcher for Smartphones, Tablets! Comes Bundled with Kids Safe Browser, Kids Video Player (with educationalists selected f...
- [**Kids Safe Search Engine - Android Apps on Google Play**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_rickblues.SafeSearch&hl=en)
   
  Shop Google Play on the web. Purchase and enjoy instantly on your Android phone or tablet without the hassle of syncing.
- [**site:play.google.com/store/apps free -"free trial" "safe search" OR "parental control"** - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?num=35&newwindow=1&q=site%3Aplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps+free++-%22free+trial%22+%22safe+search%22++OR+%22parental+control%22)

Comment: What about a kindle fire HD? Were is this at on the kindle fire HD?

Comment: Google Safe search is set in Google Preferences: -- 
https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/510?hl=en  -- 
https://support.google.com/preferences

Comment: Have modified my answer to include selecting an APP,  though the Google safe search should provide much of the same protection.

Comment: It looks like I cannot download these apps. I have apps on my kindle, but it doesn't look like any are up to my expectations.

Comment: There is an installation called userscript that can block youtube but it does not work on silk browser. Any apps or downloads specific to silk browser.